# How to use value stored in variable for RAW query

Tags: sequelize.js

I am writing a RAW SQL for sequelize (6.5.x) on Nodejs for Postresql 11. Here is an example of the raw query:

```
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
let sql = "SELECT * from messages WHERE sender_id = 1";
const msgs = await sequelize.query(sql, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

if `sender_id` is stored in a variable `senderID`, how to use variable `senderID` in the raw query above?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like

```
const { QueryTypes } = require("sequelize");
let sql = "SELECT * from messages WHERE sender_id = ?";
const msgs = await sequelize.query(sql, {
  replacements: [senderID],
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
});
```

or

```
const { QueryTypes } = require("sequelize");
let sql = "SELECT * from messages WHERE sender_id = :senderID";
const msgs = await sequelize.query(sql, {
  replacements: { senderID },
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
});
```

You could find more details in [Replacement](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements) section in the doc